# scala replace text inside NodeSeq with a NodeSeq

Tags: xml, scala

I have some code that looks something like this...

```
val text = "<em>emphasized</em>"
val xml = <span>This is some {text} xml</span>
```

"text" value actually comes from a database, but it will be a string value which contains the "em" element tags.

My question is how to convert the 2 String tags, "<em>" and "</em>", into actual xml inside the NodeSeq... when the snippet this is placed in returns the NodeSeq, I want the "em" tag to be an actual xml element, not a string representation of the xml.

Answer (score 1):

`scala.xml.XML.loadString(String): scala.xml.Elem`

Take care: this returns an `Elem` and needs (obviously) sane XML input. The following strings will (for example) raise an exception:

```
"<em>emphasized</em><a/>" // no Elem but a NodeSeq
"<em>empha<sized</em>" // invalid XML
```

You can sanitise the first string by adding some dummy XML tag around.

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting "Content is not allowed in prolog" type errors. I also tested this using a clean / sanitized / hardcoded string with no xml errors, and get the same error. I suspect the "loadString" actually requires a full xml tree including prolog?

Comment: @user85116 If you try that very example you displayed and replace `text` with `scala.xml.XML loadString text`, it works. So, if it doesn't for you, then you are not giving us enough information.

Comment: I see the problem now... the "text" variable is not valid xml all by itself (for example it might be "some <em>text</em>"... the "some" at the front is obviously the issue.) However, the final combined NodeSeq would have been valid xml with the "some" out in front; it should have converted into "<span>some <em>text</em></span>".

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer, if you don't have a valid XML snippet, is to compose `xml` as a `String`, and then convert everything to XML using `XML.loadString`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... please see my comment to Debilski.